# Web Crawler written in dart

Tags: dart

I is there a easy way to write Web Crawler in dart ?
Basically i want to Crawl AJAX and non-AJAX site and collect few information from each page. is html5lib is an option to achieve it ?

Thanks in Advance!
Ravindra

Comment: You might want to rephrase the question - "easy" is subjective. My easy might not be your easy.   Try listing what you've attempted so far, and come up with a question that has a concrete and definitive answer.   (My answer to the question asked above is "Yes" - which is probably not too helpful!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of a web crawler library build with Dart. However, all the pieces should be there. The Dart VM can connect to HTTP resources, and you can use HTML5Lib to parse the page.

Crawling AJAX requires a JavaScript interpreter. I am not aware of a JavaScript interpreter written in Dart, but you might be able to use a headless web browser (like DumpRenderTree).